# RxJava double doOnError not shown

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-android

I am using RxJava with Retrofit2, trying to **consume an API with multiple calls to it, but I want to display a different error message depending on the API call**. So, the error I pass on the ***subscribe*** method it works whenever something happens, as well as the ***doOnError*** method also writes the log I want (last doOnError call below).

The problem begins when I want to set a ***doOnError*** method inside the first ***flatMap***. So, when I tried, it is supposed to show a message... but it does not, and what it is actually executed is the consumer inside the subscribe method.

```
try {
    api = APIClient.getApiService();

    Single.fromCallable(() -> generateReport(reportInfo))
          .flatMap(report -> api.sendHashCode(new HashObject(report))
                .doOnError(t -> showMessage("THIS ERROR IS NOT SHOWN" + t.getMessage())))
          .flatMap(response -> api.getSMS(new Signature(response.getSignatureId())))
          .doOnError(t -> generateExceptionLog(t.getMessage()))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(onSuccess, onError);
} catch (Exception e) {
        generateExceptionLog(e);
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: The only scenario that I can see the first error not being trigger is if `generateReport` throws an Error instead of `api.sendHashCode`. Could this be happening or you are sure the error is in the api call?

Comment: it can happen, sure, in any method called

Comment: Try moving doOnError to outside of flatMap to see if that's the case.